# Access to MS Graph blocked by Conditional Access policy

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

To read information via the Graph API from our Azure environment I used Microsoft.Identity.Client library (version 4.18) to authenticate users. Net framework 4.8 in the background.
This works perfect for some time but now a Conditional Access policy was enabled and the following call ends in an exception.

*authResult = Await PublicApp.AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth(m_scopes).ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(False)*

**Exception: AADSTS53001: Device is not in required device state: domain_joined. Conditional Access policy requires a domain joined device, and the device is not domain joined.**

> dsregcmd /status

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Device State                                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

```
         AzureAdJoined : YES
      EnterpriseJoined : NO
          DomainJoined : YES
```

From my point of view my device is domain joined and there is no reason to block this access.
Same pc as before. Can be tested in parallel. App used with a user without conditional access works. App used with a user who has an conditional access policy assigned fails.

Any idea what I have to change to run my call also with Conditional Access enabled?